# How can i save graphics.copyfromscreen to a bitmap file on hard disk?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a button click event:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            painting = false;
            pictureBox2.Invalidate();
        }
```

Then in the paint event:

```
private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Point pnt;

            if (rect.Width > 10 && rect.Height > 10)
            {
                pnt = PointToScreen(pictureBox1.Location);
                e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                e.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(pnt.X + rect.X, pnt.Y + rect.Y, rect.X, rect.Y, new Size(rect.Width, rect.Height));
            }
        }
```

I want to save to a bitmap file not the whole pictureBox2.Image but only the CopyFromScreen part.

This is a screenshot of pictureBox2

[image: screenshot]

The pictureBox2 in the screenshot borders are also the white color around the image. But I want to save only the image not the whole pictureBox2.Image and to do it before the pictureBox2 paint event maybe in the button click event. So the image only will be saved to a bitmap.

Comment: can you use `pictureBox.Image.Save();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all what you want is to save something from the Graphics object (whether you have used the CopyFromScreen call or not), you can refer to something that have been posted here before:
[Saving System.Drawing.Graphics to a png or bmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928845/saving-system-drawing-graphics-to-a-png-or-bmp)

Or even there: [How does the Graphics CopyFromScreen method copy into a bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953581/how-does-the-graphics-copyfromscreen-method-copy-into-a-bitmap)

Please note that you don't necessarily need to use the PictureBox Paint event handler for that.

Let me know whether this answers your question =]